# Android Studio Login with SQLite database

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Currently I am developing a personal software that is able to use the database to store the registered accounts and when logging in will retrieve the data from the database to compare with the characters been entered by the user.
But for some reason, even though I entered it correctly, I can't log in successfully

This is SQLite java file

```
    package anhtuan.example.sample.SQLite;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

    import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

    public class SQLite extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public SQLite(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, "System", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        String account = "create table accounts " +
                "(" +
                "_id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                "user text," +
                "password text" +
                ")";
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(account);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("drop table if exists accounts");
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }
    }
```

Here are DAO java file

```
    package anhtuan.example.sample.DAO;

    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import anhtuan.example.sample.Log.SignUp;
    import anhtuan.example.sample.Model.AccountModel;
    import anhtuan.example.sample.SQLite.SQLite;

    public class DAO {
    SQLite sqLite;
    ArrayList<AccountModel> ds = new ArrayList<>();
    public DAO(Context context) {
        sqLite = new SQLite(context);
    }

    public void addUser(String acc, String pass) {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = sqLite.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("user",acc);
        values.put("password",pass);
        sqLiteDatabase.insert("accounts", null, values);
    }

    public ArrayList<AccountModel> getDSAccount(){
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = sqLite.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("select * from accounts", null);
        if(c.getCount()>0){
            c.moveToFirst();
            do {
                ds.add(new AccountModel(c.getString(1),c.getString(2)));
            }while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        return ds;
    }

    public boolean checkLogin(Context context,String users,String passwords){
        ds = getDSAccount();
        for(int i = 0; i < ds.size();i++){
        if(ds.get(i).getUser().equals(users)){
            if(passwords.equals(ds.get(i).getPassword())){
                return true;
            }
        }
        };
        return false;
    }

    public boolean changePass(String user,String password){

        return true;
    }
    }
```

And lastly the signin java file

```
    package anhtuan.example.sample.Log;

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;  
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import anhtuan.example.sample.DAO.DAO;
    import anhtuan.example.sample.Home;
    import anhtuan.example.sample.Model.AccountModel;
    import anhtuan.example.sample.R;

    public class SignIn extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextInputEditText user,pass;
    TextView signup;
    Button Login;

    DAO dao;
    ArrayList<AccountModel> ds;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);
        setTitle("Sign In");
        user = findViewById(R.id.SIuser);
        pass = findViewById(R.id.SIpass);
        Login = findViewById(R.id.SIbtn);
        signup = findViewById(R.id.SItv);

        dao = new DAO(this);

        signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(SignIn.this,ForgotPass.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        String Loginuser = user.getText().toString();
        String Loginpasse = pass.getText().toString();

        Login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(user.getText().length() == 0 || pass.getText().length() == 0){
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SignIn.this);
                    builder.setTitle("You haven't insert all the blank");
                    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        }
                    });
                    builder.show();
                }else{
                    if(dao.checkLogin(SignIn.this,Loginuser,Loginpasse)){
                        Intent i = new Intent(SignIn.this,Home.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }else{
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SignIn.this);
                        builder.setTitle("Check again !");
                        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            }
                        });
                        builder.show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
    }
```

I had try to use contain and indexOf with arrayList to find the data without using for loop but it always come out false so i decide to use for loop again.

Comment: Why read the entire table into an `ArrayList` rather than query the table for a specific user? May I also suggest doing this using Room (https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room) to avoid a lot of boilerplate code and chance of errors?

Comment: Actually, I'm just a student learning how to create applications, so my experience and thinking about how to use it are quite poor, the concepts are still flawed, so I only know what to do. be learned. But thanks anyway, I think this "room" will help me grow more